# Google Calendar API: KeyError: 'location'

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

in using the google calendar api (with python), I've been able to get back the variables I want, so I can export events into a text file. However, one variable (the location) is triggering an error and I'm not sure why.

This is straight from google's start code, with additions by me for the variables I want:

```
   if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
#    print(start, event['summary'], event['description'], event['location'],  event['iCalUID'])
    print(start, event['summary'], event['location'], event['iCalUID'])
```

It prints a list of upcoming appointments including the location, but it stops and throws this error at me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryingnewstuff.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(start, event['summary'], event['description'], event['location'],  event['iCalUID'])
KeyError: 'location'
```

Is this a problem with credentials/json? Am I using an old version of google calendar api? How do I check that? My json file says {"_module": "oauth2client.client", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"], "

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, I thought that you want to know about the reason of `KeyError: 'location'`. But from your replying, it seems that my understanding was not correct. So I have to remove my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Then, from `It is getting the summary and even the location just fine`, in your situation, even when the property of `location` is included in the object of the element, the error occurs. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the whole script and values for completely replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that I just needed to upgrade to the latest google API. I didn't end up using it anyway. But thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

If you want change setting on "scope" variable. 
maybe you can delete credential file, And add scope array, last rerun your .py file